# LTC 2065 is not working between 2 V - 4 V power supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass, active-filter, high-pass-filter

I'm having a problem with the LTC2065 operational amplifier design. I use a 3.3V supply as I show in the picture, and after boosting my input signal I make it oscillate at 1.8V using a 1.8V virtual ground.
Everything is normal until the low pass filter (U4) output. I see the signal I give from the input at the output with as much gain as I expected, and I use the same opamp in the high pass filter (U2), but here I get the wrong output signal. The strange thing is that when I give my supply signal a voltage of 4 V or above, my system works without any problems.
Below I give my circuit and signal outputs. How can I find a solution for my design, what am I missing?

Pictures
(

2 - Low pass output with 3.3 V supply (V2)

3 - High pass output with 3.3 V supply  (V2)

4 - Low pass output with 5 V supply (V2)

5 - High pass output with 5 V supply  (V2)
)

[image: Low pass output with 3.3 V supply (V2)]

[image: High pass output with 3.3 V supply (V2)]

[image: Low pass output with 5 V supply (V2)]

[image: High pass output with 5V supply (V2)]

Comment: Pricey buggers. But they do say rail to rail I/O on the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc2063-2064-2065.pdf). And the operating supply rail voltage difference supports yours. So that means we can look closer.

Comment: What's your logic for C9 and the input for U4? (There's no galvanic connection of the opamp inpuit to anything else.)

Comment: @periblepsis C9 is the ingredient of the multifeedback low pass filter and the input of the opamp is the output of the sinus that is amplified in inamp. Vref is the virtual ground of the system that helps swing the signal on the 1.8 (Vref) instead of 0 V  ( ground ). The system is working with single supply. Without Vref, no signal can show up lower than 0 V
Can you please open it up, I couldn't get the point that you touched

Comment: I'd like to see the web site or be told about the textbook that lays out that particular MFB low pass. Here's, for example, [one from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa231/sboa231.pdf?ts=1696261199775).